# How to properly iterate through a large 2D array and log the results of passing its arrays into a method

Tags: javascript, arrays, debugging, iteration

I am trying my hand at Javascript after learning a number of other coding languages.

****Edit**** I fixed the problem, I simply had to use the *let* keyword in both outer for loops which used *i* as the same name for the iterator variable.

I have a 2D int array with 29 rows, each of which contains an array of length 744 (744 * 29 = 21576 numbers), and I would like to pass each array, or column, into a method that performs math expressions (i.e the mean of all values, the standard deviation, etc) and log the results to my console. When I attempt to do so, the loop only outputs results of the computation of the numbers in the 1st array, and none of the others. I may be wrong, but I have a feeling the solution may have something to do with awaiting for a result and/or exploiting asynchronous behavior, or my misunderstanding of how to deal with an array as an object.

First and foremost, I have written all of my active code within an fs.readFile method, which reads through a JSON file that provides me with my desired data.

```
fs.readFile('./doc.json', 'utf-8', (err, text) => {...
```

The resulting data is an array of objects. The following is the hierarchy of information found within the array. I use a *triple for loop* to access the desired data and populate my 2D array. (I know that this is not nearly the most efficient way of accomplishing this, but I figure it should work nonetheless)

```
//Array [
    //Object {...
        //Property: inner Array[
            //inner Object {...
                //Desired Property: object which contains the desired values{...}
                 // },...
               // ]
             // },...
           // ]
for(let i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++){
    for(let j = 0; j < dataArray[i].property.length; j++){
        let valueArray = Object.values(dataArray[i].property[j].desiredProperty).slice(0);
        for(let c = 0; c < valueArray.length; c++;){
            arr[c][(i * dataArray[i].property.length) + j] = valueArray[c];
        }
    }
}
```

After populating it, I have no problem iterating through the 2D array and simply logging every array of numbers to the console (the following loop is outside of the previous loop)

```
for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    console.log("array number " + (i + 1) + ": " + arr[i]);
}
```

However, when I attempt to pass the same array into a GetTotal method (retrieves the total of all numbers in the array) and store the result, the program outputs the mean of the first array of numbers, and immediately ends.

```
for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    console.log("array number " + (i + 1) + ": " + arr[i]);
    let tot = GetTotal(arr[i]);
    console.log("\nTotal: " + tot);
}

function GetTotal(nums){
  let sum = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
    sum += nums[i];
  }
  return sum;
}
```

**Not quite sure how to post pictures here, I'm sure those would be helpful to better visualize the situation**

I initialize my 2D array using a Create2DArray method, then populate each new array with zeroes:

```
var arr= Create2DArray(numRows, numCols);
for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  for(j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++){
    arr[i][j] = 0;
  }
}
function Create2DArray(rows,cols){
  let newArr = [];
  for(i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    newArr.push(new Array(cols));
  }
  return newArr;
}
```

I would like to see the result of performing the method's computations on ALL arrays of numbers instead of just the first.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I was unable to recreate your issue after populating the arrays with random values.  Perhaps a more complete code example showing the scoped relationships of the parts within the process might offer a clue?  See [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BnPck/n8hz94f5/6/);

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I added more information about accessing/populating the data. All of the other code is just storing and debugging different values like finding the standard deviation, finding stdDev outlyers, greatest average, greatest total, etc

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of have understood what exactly are you looking for. This would be my approach to this kind of problems :

```js
var dataArray = [
  {propertyArr : [{prop1 : 1, prop2 : 2}, {prop1 : 1, prop2 : 2}]},
  {propertyArr : [{prop1 : 3, prop2 : 4}, {prop1 : 3, prop2 : 4}]},
  {propertyArr : [{prop1 : 5, prop2 : 6}, {prop1 : 5, prop2 : 6}]}
]

var valueArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] ;

var resultValues = dataArray.map((element,i) => {
  var arr = element.propertyArr.map((object,j) => {
      var value = valueArray[object.prop1] + valueArray[object.prop2] ;
      return value ;
  })
  return arr ;  
});

resultValues.forEach((elementArr,i) => {
  elementArr.forEach((element2Arr,j)=>{
    console.log(`resultValues[${i},${j}] : [${resultValues[i][j]}]`) ;                  
  })                       
})
```